# jquery treeview highlight only current item

Tags: jquery, treeview, highlighting

Need a little help: I'm using jquery treeview plugin (this one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/). And I'd like to do highlighting the current item. I'm doing it this way:

CSS:

```
.filetree li .clicked {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And JS code:

```
$('li').live('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this.id);
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    return false;
});
```

Everything works fine, but all items are highlighted together with its child elements, and the root elements are not highlighted in a whole.

How can I make a highlighting of only current item? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the right way is:

```
 $(event.target).addClass('clicked');
```

instead of

```
 $(this).addClass('clicked');
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you are applying a `bold` font to the entire `li` element. If you look at the markup, the `li` has a child `ul` which represents all its child elements.

Therefore, in your css you should try to just apply the `bold` to the `span` that has the name, not the entire `li` node:

```
.filetree li.clicked > span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

See here for information about child selectors:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors